# How to make conditional order by statement with multiple data types, sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

**I tried to do so, but my data types are char and date**

```
select * from table_name   
    where
    smthng 
    order by  
    case when to_date(to_char( :edate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')-
    to_date(to_char( :sdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')>0  
    then ddate   
    else  department end
```

Comment: The `case` expression also needs a terminating `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the outputs from a `CASE` statement must have the same data-type and since you can't convert `department` to a `DATE` data-type then you will need to convert `ddate` to a String or else have two `CASE` statements with mutually exclusive conditions.

Some additional points:

- Firstly, you don't need to convert `:sdate` and `:edate` from a `DATE` data type to a string and then back to a `DATE`; just perform the comparison on the `DATE`s.
- Secondly, as you are doing this in the `ORDER BY` clause then you need to make sure what you are ordering by makes sense. Ordering by a date formatted as a `'dd.mm.yyyy'` string does not make sense as it will perform an alpha-numeric string comparison and not a comparison in ascending date order. If you do want to use a single case statement and convert both to strings then use an ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD` which will let you order the formatted date string using an alpha-numberic sort.

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  something
ORDER BY
       CASE
       WHEN :edate > :sdate
       THEN TO_CHAR( ddate ,'YYYY-MM-DD' )
       ELSE department
       END
```

or you can just use 2 `CASE` statements, one for each mutually exclusive case and defaulting each to `NULL` (or some other constant) when it does not match:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  something
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN :edate > :sdate THEN ddate ELSE NULL       END,
       CASE WHEN :edate > :sdate THEN NULL  ELSE department END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any conversion for substraction considering `:edate` and `:sdate` are of type date

```
select *
  from table_name
 where smthng
 order by case
            when :edate - :sdate > 0 then
             to_char(ddate ,'dd.mm.yyyy')
            else
             department
            end
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in  order  must match the data type so if you need  can't return date or string  but a single data type only  A8ssuming department is a strint data type you should convert data as char)

```
select * 
from table_name   
where .......   smthng .... 
order by  
  case when to_date(to_char( :edate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')-
    to_date(to_char( :sdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')>0  
    then to_char(ddate ,    'dd.mm.yyyy')
 else  department
  end
```